# .NET reflection - getting the first item out of a reflected collection without casting to specific collection

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I've got a Customer object with a Collection of CustomerContacts

```
IEnumerable<CustomerContact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

In some other code I'm using Reflection and have the PropertyInfo of Contacts property

```
var contacts = propertyInfo.GetValue(customerObject, null);
```

I know contacts has at least one object in it, but how do I get it out?  I don't want to Cast it to `IEnumerable<CustomerContact>` because I want to keep my reflection method dynamic.  I thought about calling FirstOrDefault() by reflection - but can't do that easily because its an extension method.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I need to keep the reflection method dynamic.  I've reduced the code to show just the problem, if you saw it in context I doubt you'd suggest that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to avoid mentioning `CustomerContact` in your code, you could do this:

```
IEnumerable items = (IEnumerable)propertyInfo.GetValue(customerObject, null);

object first = items.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
```